# Not repeating myself

Tags: javascript, function, dry

I am trying to make code to make squares change color when I click on them:

```
function change(image) {
switch (image) {
    case 1:
        var image = document.getElementById('first');
        if (image.src.match("square1.png")) {
            image.src = "squareblue1.jpg";
        } else {
            image.src = "square1.png";
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        var image = document.getElementById('second');
        if (image.src.match("square1.png")) {
            image.src = "squareblue1.jpg";
        } else {
            image.src = "square1.png";
        }
        break;
    case 3:
        var image = document.getElementById('third');
        if (image.src.match("square1.png")) {
            image.src = "squareblue1.jpg";
        } else {
            image.src = "square1.png";
        }
        break;
    default:
    var image = document.getElementById('forth');
        if (image.src.match("square1.png")) {
            image.src = "squareblue1.jpg";
        } else {
            image.src = "square1.png";
        }
        break;
```

I am repeating this section over and over again:

```
if (image.src.match("square1.png")) {
            image.src = "squareblue1.jpg";
        } else {
            image.src = "square1.png";
        }
```

I tried to turn it into a function but the function would have to be called "image" or else an error will pop up saying that image is not defined and I already used image in another variable. Is there a way to shorten my code by putting it in a function?

Comment: did you know your `var image`s are all the same var.  JavaScript has function-scoped variables.  There are no block-scoped variables, like in Java.

Comment: Tip.. When these squares are all plain solid non transparent colors, then it's best that you just use css `background-color` or `background`. Saves you from having to load images, taking bandwidth.

Comment: This is what class names are for.

Comment: This is a code review question, and is either too broad or primarily opinion based on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var IMAGES = {
  1: 'first',
  2: 'second',
  3: 'third',
  default: 'fourth'
};
function change(image) {
    var imageID = IMAGES[image] || IMAGES.default;
    var image = document.getElementById(imageID);
    if (image.src.match("square1.png")) {
        image.src = "squareblue1.jpg";
    } else {
        image.src = "square1.png";
    }
}
```

This is the literal DRY-up of your code. However, a reimplementation would be better. For instance, having background styling instead of image elements would allow you to do the same just by adding or removing a class.

Comment: works except for the last picture "forth" Is there a fix?

Comment: It should work. How, specifically, does it not work for you? Is there an error? Does the wrong thing get toggled? Does nothing happen?

Comment: sorry just spelt fourth "forth" xD.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to use an array containing the element ids, this way:

```
function change(image) {

  var ids = [
    null,
    'first',
    'second',
    'third',
    'forth'
  ];

  var img = document.getElementById(ids[image]);
  img.src = image.src.match('square1.png') ?
    'squareblue1.jpg' :
    'square1.png';
}
```

Comment: But you didn't actually use your array...

Answer (score 0):

Include the jQuery

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Then you can just make the colors change whenever a image is clicked, but make the function only change `this` image

```
$("img").click(function(){
    $(this).src = "new src";
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: He is asking to convert his current code into a functions.

Comment: @JomarSevillejo proposing an idea.

Comment: [I think it's pretty excessive to import a library for such a simple task](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48195/161479).

Comment: @Gary Thanks! I'm still in the process of learning, so I'll keep that in mind

Answer (score 0):

How about using a different variable name?

```
function change (image) {
   switch (image) {
      case 1:
         changeSrc('first');
         break;
      case 2:
         changeSrc('second');
         break;
      ...

   function changeSrc (id) {
      var image = document.getElementById(id);
      if (image.src.match("square1.png")) {
          image.src = "squareblue1.jpg";
      } else {
          image.src = "square1.png";
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Would love some feedback on why this is a -1

Comment: For starters, your switch has no breaks, so they'll all end up the same.  Second, the code still seems needlessly repetitive.  I agree with the other answers that an array or object would be most appropriate.  Not the downvoter though.

Comment: That was a mistake (good catch!), but OP was specific about his desired outcome so although I agree this isn't an ideal solution, it does fit the question's requirements.

Comment: It does, which is why I didn't downvote.  It's just not very clean IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you can do is simply use the `switch` to define the `image` variable, then do what you need with it.

```
var image;
switch(image) {
    case 1:
        image = document.getElementById('first');
        break;
    case 2:
        image = document.getElementById('second');
        break;
    ...
}

if (image.src.match("square1.png")) {
    image.src = "squareblue1.jpg";
} else {
    image.src = "square1.png";
}
```

If you prefer, you could also extract the lines that changes the `src` into a function. This would be useful if other functions also do this.